# Blazor WASM authentication in Chrome Incognito

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I do have a Blazor WASM (.NET 6) application that is using an Identity Server hosted on different URL for authentication.
I'm configuring the authentication like this:

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.ProviderOptions.Authority = configuration.OidcAuthority;
    options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = configuration.OidcClientId;
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = configuration.OidcResponseType;
    options.ProviderOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri = configuration.OidcPostLogoutRedirectUri;
    options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri = configuration.OidcRedirectUri;
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes = configuration.DefaultScopes;
});
```

Everything works great locally and in production as well.
The problem occurs when I want to open the page in Chrome Incognito window with Third party cookies disabled.
I see in the browser that during authorization process I receive cookies with *SameSite=None* and *Secure=true*, but this cookie is not send with

```
https://login.myidserver.net/connect/authorize?client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=h...
```

as oppose to normal Chrome window.

Because of that I receive back

```
https://localhost:12345/authentication/login-callback?error=login_required&state=....
```

and *access_token* is not saved in session storage as it should be.

Is there any way to overcome this and force the cookie to be used in this case?
Or am I misunderstanding something?

All the solutions I've seen on the internet seems not to work for me.

Edit:
Ok, why is authorize called right after sucessful authentication and receiving of the token?. I understand I cannot force to send this cookie but can I somehow avoid do this authorize call when I'm right after successful login?

Comment: Hi, your sso won't work in incognito. Chrome won't send the third party cookie on the call to /authorize which will make identity server redirect you to the login page.

Comment: Take a look at this page where they explain how to make incognito mode send cookies, without them it won't work. https://knowledge.kaltura.com/help/enabling-3rd-party-cookies-for-chrome-incognito-mode

Comment: Thank you, but maybe I can avoid /authorize call in Blazor when I just sucessfully authenticated? I have an access token and I assume authorize is not needed right after successful log in.

Comment: /authorize is part of the OIDC flow, whether in Blazor or not, if you're doing OIDC Code + PKCE token flow, you need the call to authorize, and then the token endpoint.